# passing arguments to a recursive function javaScript

Tags: javascript, recursion

I understood that the best practice with setTimeOut is sending an anonymous function with the function I want to redo inside. 
Why won't it work?

```
function movement(dir) {
    ...
    ...
        setTimeOut(function (){movement(dir);},21);
```

Comment: It does work: http://jsfiddle.net/8neft/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will work. Of course, the name of the function is `setTimeout()` instead of `setTimeOut()`. See this example:

```
function movement(dir) {
  console.log(dir);
  if (dir++ < 5) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      movement(dir);
    }, 21);
  }
};

movement(1);
```

It prints:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```